# Magento2 plugin/interceptor not working

Tags: magento, magento2

I have following action:

`http://localhost/admin/catalog/product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/135/key/…/`

I would like to do some extra things with attribute after saving.
I have created and registered custom plugin in `Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/Save.php` with following content:

```
class Save
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
     protected $config;


    /**
     * @param Config $config
     */
    public function __construct(Config $config, TypeListInterface $typeList)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Attribute $subject
     * @param Attribute $result
     * @return Attribute $result
     *
     */
    public function afterSave(Attribute $subject, Attribute $result)
    {
        # Do something
    }
}
```

I have also added following entry to `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute">
    <plugin name="do_stuff_after_attribute_save" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Save" />
</type>
```

But the plugin seems not to work. Even if I `die('somenthing');` or try to log to file, the code is not executed after saving the attribute.

Maybe I am trying to overwrite wrong method?

Comment: Magento generates the interceptors which handle plugin calls. Make sure to remove generated code after adding your plugin `rm -rf var/generated/*` or `rm -rf generated/*`.

Answer (score 1):

**You could follow the points below:**

1. You should use `di.xml` in the `adminhtml` folder as it is a backend issue.
2. You should override the `execute` method of this `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save` controller class.

**File:** `app/code/Milandev/Testplugin/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Milandev_Admin_Product_Attribute_Save" sortOrder="10" type="Milandev\Testplugin\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**File:** `app/code/Milandev/Testplugin/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Save.php`

```
<?php
namespace Milandev\Testplugin\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute;

class Save
{

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        die('hello world!');
        //Your plugin code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make sure that your plugin is applied and all other plugins return expected values.

1. Go to `generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php` (if it's already generated). If not, just enable `developer` mode (it will be generated automatically) or run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` for production mode.
2. Look for `afterSave()` method and print the list of available plugins. E.g.

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function afterSave()
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'afterSave');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($pluginInfo);
        die;
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::afterSave();
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('afterSave', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }
```

3. Then you should see the list of enabled plugins (in your case it might be `save_swatches_option_params` ). Just look for matches in the code and make sure all of them return EXPECTED results. By default, "after" plugins should return the same `$result` as the original method does. Otherwise, the next plugins will not work correctly, like in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue some time ago. Turned out that there was another plugin installed which tried to handle the exact same class and property. After adding the sortOrder attribute on both di.xml files, with of course a different value for both, everything worked fine.